# Cycle mages javascript

Tags: image

So I am trying to cycle through images using two buttons on a website. Here is my js:

```
var counter = 0

function changeImage() {
if(counter == 0){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src =   "url image";
    counter++;
}
else if(counter == 1){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "url image";
    counter++;
}
else if(counter == 2){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "url image";
    counter = 0;
}
};

function changeImage1() {
if(counter == 0){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "url image";
    counter = 2;
}
else if(counter == 1){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "url image";
    counter--;
}
else if(counter == 2){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "url image";
    counter--;
}
};
```

When I cycle through images one way it works fine, but when I try and switch directions it double cycles. Why is that?